# How to correlate non-numeric vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two non-numeric vectors that are as follows: 
aluOrientation vector contains one of the two strings: Complementary and Direct
aluFamily vector contains one of the three strings: AluS, AluY, AluJ
Both are of size 36.

I want to correlate these two. That is I want to know how strong the association is between, for example, Complementary and Alu S. I know how to do a correlation test with numerical variables. But those methods, for example, kendall, does not work for a non-numeric variable.

I tried changing my vectors into factors in R. But it doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone know a function or a package in R that can correlate two non-numeric vectors?

Comment: maybe use `table`

Comment: without knowing more of what these variables are, try  `?chisq.test`

Comment: Yupm chisq.test works perfectly fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aluOrientation <- rep (c("Complementary", "Direct"), 18)
aluFamily      <- rep(c("AluS", "AluY", "AluJ"), 12)
```

One way to do this is factor analysis:

```
df1 <- data.frame(aluOrientation, aluFamily)

library(psych)
fa(r = cor(model.matrix(~aluFamily + aluOrientation  - 1, data = df1)), 
   rotate = "none", fm = "pa")
```

> ```
> Standardized loadings (pattern matrix) based upon correlation matrix
>                        PA1      h2    u2 com
> aluFamilyAluJ         1.73 3.0e+00 -1.99   1
> aluFamilyAluS        -0.24 5.9e-02  0.94   1
> aluFamilyAluY        -0.24 5.9e-02  0.94   1
> aluOrientationDirect  0.00 1.0e-30  1.00   1
>
>                 PA1
> SS loadings    3.11
> Proportion Var 0.78
>
> Mean item complexity =  1
> Test of the hypothesis that 1 factor is sufficient.
>
> The degrees of freedom for the null model are  6  and the objective function was  5.5
> The degrees of freedom for the model are 2  and the objective function was  NaN 
>
> The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.23 
> The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.4 
>
> Fit based upon off diagonal values = 0.57
> ```

For more details:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/whatstat/whatstat.htm#factor

Comment: Thanks :) you literally saved me here.

Comment: @Laurenboomer Happy to help!